# How many ways can we distinctly choose five pieces of salami?

Tags: combinatorics

The question is as follows

> We have six kinds of salami that have ten pieces and one kind of salami that has four pieces. How many ways can we distinctly choose five pieces of salami?

The answer is 461. It can be found here along with a detailed solution: https://www.hackmath.net/en/math-problem/4737?result=1

The problem I am having is that I do not understand the question. For instance: "We have six kinds of salami that have ten pieces". What does that mean? Does it mean:

We have 60 salami? 10 of type 1, 10 of type 2,...,10 of type 6? If so, I don't understand the solution.

Could someone give a helping hand?

I need some way of counting numbers that sum to 5 over the following slots:

[][][][][][][]

The first six can go up to 10 and the last one up to 4, remembering that the sum is equal to 5. So an example would be

[][][][][][1][4]

[][][][2][1][1][1]

and so on.

Comment: In total, there are $64 = 6 \cdot 10 + 4$ pieces of salami, with $10$ each of the first six types and four of the seventh type.

Comment: Yes. That is what I thought. As you can see above, I am trying to put together a solution method. But I just don't know how to transfer my idea to concrete mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In total, there are $64 = 6 \cdot 10 + 4$ pieces of salami, with $10$ of each of the first six types and four of the seventh type.  The problem asks in how many ways we can select five of these $64$ pieces.

Let $x_i$ be the number of pieces of type $i$ that are selected.  Then we seek the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 = 5 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_i \leq 10$ for $1 \leq i \leq 6$ and $x_7 \leq 4$.  Notice that the only restriction that we can violate by selecting four pieces of salami is $x_7 \leq 4$.  Moreover, the only way to violate that restriction is to select five pieces of salami of the seventh type.

If there were no restrictions, a particular solution of equation $1$ would correspond to placing $7 - 1 = 6$ addition signs in a row of five ones.  For instance,
$$+ 1 + + 1 1 + 1 + + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 1, x_3 = 0, x_4 = 2, x_5 = 1, x_6 = 0, x_7 = 1$.  Thus, the number of solutions of equation $1$ in the nonnegative integers correspond to the number of ways we can place six addition signs in a row of five ones, which is
$$\binom{5 + 7 - 1}{7 - 1} = \binom{11}{6}$$
since we must choose which $7 - 1 = 6$ of the $5 + 7 - 1 = 11$ positions required for five ones and six addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Since the solution $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = x_6 = 0, x_7 = 5$ violates the restriction that $x_7 \leq 4$, we must subtract one from the total, which yields
$$\binom{11}{6} - 1$$
possible selections.

In the linked solution, the author considers cases, depending on the number of pieces of salami of the seventh type that are selected.

If $k$ pieces of the seventh type are selected, where $0 \leq k \leq 4$, then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + k = 5$$
so
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 5 - k \tag{2}$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{5 - k + 6 - 1}{6 - 1} = \binom{10 - k}{5}$$
solutions.  Summing over the possible values of $k$ yields
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{4} \binom{10 - k}{5} = \binom{10}{5} + \binom{9}{5} + \binom{8}{5} + \binom{7}{5} + \binom{6}{5}$$

The two results are equivalent because of the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: There are a few things I don't understand. "If there were no restrictions, a particular solution of equation 1 would correspond  to placing 7−1=6 addition signs in a row of five ones... ". Is this a common result? I have never seen this before.

Comment: Also "so $x_1+x_2 + .... + x_6 = 5-k$ which is an equation in the non-negative integers with .... solutions" I don't understand that result either.

Comment: For your first question, see [Theorem 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) on the linked page.  For the second question, remember that $x_i$ represents the number of pieces of salami of type $i$ that are selected. If $k$ pieces of the seventh type are selected, then $5 - k$ pieces of the remaining six types are selected.  Hence, $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 5 - k$, where each $x_i$ is a nonnegative integer.

Comment: @JMP Thank you for inserting the missing term.

Comment: You are a hero. Thanks :)